# telnetd: getpty: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, telnet

```
root@hj-ibmibm1677:~# telnet localhost
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
telnetd: getpty: No such file or directory
.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

this is what happens when i try to `telnet` to localhost.

If someone can help me to apply the required patch than it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me to install telnetd on the vm = > http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux